# dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory after upgrading to lxc-docker

Tags: docker

when I installed docker initially, it shows to be of version 1.0.1
Being, that the current version is 1.4.1, I found and executed the following instructions:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install docker.io

$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/docker.io /usr/local/bin/docker

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9

$ sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main \
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

Now, when I run docker version I get 1.4.1, but docker no longer works - it gives me this error:

```
root@8dedd2fff58e:/# docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

What can I do to fox this, but retail the most current docker verion 1.4.1?

Comment: any luck? encountering the same issue...

Comment: In my case, it helps to start running docker explicitly on tcp, as oppose to .sock:  sudo docker -H my_ip:2365 -d &      The details are described here:    https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/

Comment: sorry - the port is actually 2375, not 2365

Answer (score 27):

/var/run/docker will be created when you start the docker service:

systemd:

`sudo systemctl start docker`

upstart:

`sudo service docker start`

init.d:

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker start`

You might also need this if you get this error:
`FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?`

Comment: when I ran service docker status I get : docker is not running, and when I ran service docker start - I got mount: permission denied

Comment: did you use `sudo` or start it as root?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue on Mac OS X. Leaving my fix here in case it helps somebody:

1. Run the "Docker Quick Start Terminal"
2. In the target-directory, run `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`

This fixes the issue for me

Comment: wroks for me...  what is `eval "$(docker-machine env default)" ` doing?

Comment: @Robbo_UK `docker-machine env default` is most likely echoing a bunch of environment variables in an EXPORT statement that the eval runs in the current shell.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same problem and I was able to find the solution here: https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/.

It's always good to go back to foundations.

The problem is that you might be running on a different port instead of default socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock).

If you run "ps aux | grep docker" you should see the daemon running. At the end of the line of the docker process you should also see a parameter -H={IpAddress}:{Port}. You should also see the path were the certificates are stored (--tls parameters)

You have to instruct docker to connect to the tcp address specified in the -H parameter.

For example:

```
`docker --tls -H tcp://{IpAddress}:{Port} version`
```

Notice the --tls parameter, this is necessary if you instructed docker to run in a secure mode.

You could avoid the verbosity of the command by setting environment variables.

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://{IpAddress}:{Port}"
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Is docker initiated as a daemon?
use `service docker.io status` or `service docker status`

if not then start it and play with it

Comment: when I ran service docker status I get : docker is not running, and when I ran service docker start - I got mount: permission denied

Comment: Well then you need sudo permissions

Comment: I did run this as root

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh M1 MacBook I ran into this. Amazingly the solution was to simply log in to the app using my docker account details. Once I did that I re-ran the failed command and it worked.